# Wrap link to heading text with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Let say I have content with a bunch of headings inside (H2, H3, and maybe H4)

What I need is a simple pure javascript at the bottom of my html (before the body) that can wrap a link to each heading that exist inside the content and the `href` value is the `id` from each heading.

```html
<html>
<body>

<main>

<h2 id="foobar-link">FooBar Link</h2>
<p>Affogato +1 shaman, gochujang yr butcher organic blog hella glossier banh mi four loko tilde. Venmo beard pour-over activated charcoal health goth shoreditch banjo chicharrones blog yr helvetica hot chicken. Flexitarian succulents pinterest pug, vexillologist subway tile brunch synth edison bulb palo santo adaptogen PB</p>

<h3 id="foo">Foo</h3>
<p>Sartorial subway tile pork belly ennui salvia raclette intelligentsia waistcoat fanny pack before they sold out kogi cardigan photo booth. Biodiesel PBpoutine, post-ironic godard williamsburg pork belly skateboard fashion axe food</p>

<h4 id="bar">Bar</h4>
<p>Sartorial subway tile pork belly ennui salvia raclette intelligentsia waistcoat fanny pack before they sold out kogi cardigan photo booth. Biodiesel PBRpoutine, post-ironic godard williamsburg pork belly skateboard fashion axe food</p>


</main>

<script>
   //
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the output

```html
<html>
<body>

<main>

<h2 id="foobar-link">
<a href="/#foobar-link">FooBar Link</a>
</h2>
<p>Affogato +1 shaman, gochujang yr butcher organic blog hella glossier banh mi four loko tilde. Venmo beard pour-over activated charcoal health goth shoreditch banjo chicharrones blog yr helvetica hot chicken. Flexitarian succulents pinterest pug, vexillologist subway tile brunch synth edison bulb palo santo adaptogen PB</p>

<h3 id="foo">
<a href="/#foo">Foo</a>
</h3>
<p>Sartorial subway tile pork belly ennui salvia raclette intelligentsia waistcoat fanny pack before they sold out kogi cardigan photo booth. Biodiesel PBpoutine, post-ironic godard williamsburg pork belly skateboard fashion axe food</p>

<h4 id="bar">
<a href="/#bar">Bar</a>
</h4>
<p>Sartorial subway tile pork belly ennui salvia raclette intelligentsia waistcoat fanny pack before they sold out kogi cardigan photo booth. Biodiesel PBRpoutine, post-ironic godard williamsburg pork belly skateboard fashion axe food</p>


</main>

<script>
// the script here
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

any help would greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I would like to understand why you want this? A hyperlink to the spot where you are clicking just not seem that interesting...

Comment: And this has to be generated by JS? You cannot just add it to the markup?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hi, kindly check the update. The correct `is foobar-link`

Comment: @trincot let say the page is documentation with a lot of part and spesific instruction, in this case it can be more easier to share

Comment: @ptts yes, I have no access to the markup

Comment: You want the anchor to be inside the h1,h2? Outside is not good enough, I gather?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var headingsArr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4'));

headingsArr.forEach(h => {
  var id = h.getAttribute('id');
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', '/#' + id);
  link.innerHTML = h.innerHTML;
  h.innerHTML = link.outerHTML;
});
```

Comment: works like a cham, what if I need to add more element like svg inside the `a`?

Comment: You play with `link.innerHTML` (7 line), .e.g. `link.innerHTML = h.innerHTML + '<my-svg-tag></my-svg-tag>'`;

Answer (score 2):

```js
const headers = document.querySelectorAll('h1,h2,h3,h4')

// replace "-" with space and capitalize words
function transformId(text) {
  return text.replace('-', ' ').replace(/\b./g, (x) => x.toUpperCase());
}

headers.forEach(header => {
  header.innerText = ''
  const anchor = document.createElement('a')
  anchor.innerText = transformId(header.id)
  anchor.href = `/#${header.id}`
  header.appendChild(anchor)
})
```

```html
<h2 id="foobar-link">FooBar Link</h2>
<p>Affogato +1 shaman, gochujang yr butcher organic blog hella glossier banh mi four loko tilde. Venmo beard pour-over activated charcoal health goth shoreditch banjo chicharrones blog yr helvetica hot chicken. Flexitarian succulents pinterest pug, vexillologist
  subway tile brunch synth edison bulb palo santo adaptogen PB</p>

<h3 id="foo">Foo</h3>
<p>Sartorial subway tile pork belly ennui salvia raclette intelligentsia waistcoat fanny pack before they sold out kogi cardigan photo booth. Biodiesel PBpoutine, post-ironic godard williamsburg pork belly skateboard fashion axe food</p>

<h4 id="bar">Bar</h4>
<p>Sartorial subway tile pork belly ennui salvia raclette intelligentsia waistcoat fanny pack before they sold out kogi cardigan photo booth. Biodiesel PBRpoutine, post-ironic godard williamsburg pork belly skateboard fashion axe food</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var headings = document.querySelectorAll('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6');

headings.forEach(node => {
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.innerText = node.id;
    anchor.href = '/' + node.id;
    node.insertElement(anchor);
});
```